# c11 standard 6.7.2.3 Tags A specific type shall have its content defined at most once

Tags: c, gcc, c11

My code is below

```
1 #include <stdio.h>                                                          
2 int main(void)
3 {
4         union test1 {
5                 int a;
6         };
7 
8         union test1 {
9                 int a;
10         };
11 
12         return 0;
13 }
```

compile error :

```
4.c: In function ‘main’:
4.c:8:15: error: redefinition of ‘union test1’
    union test1 {
          ^
4.c:4:15: note: originally defined here
    union test1 {
          ^
```

My question is

Q1:
error message say redefinition,
In my thought, below code should be declaration.
Why say redefinition?
Why not redeclaration?

```
4         union test1 {
5                 int a;
6         };
```

Q2:
according c11 standard

> 6.7.2.3 Tags A specific type shall have its content defined at most once.

At most once ===>>> My code has two times, so happen error.
"A specific type"
Below code crate type ?

```
union test1 {
           int a;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have understood definition and declaration incorrectly. See the answer to the question [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration). You will see that `union test1;` is a declaration but `union test1 {int a;};` is a definition.

Also, you are defining union inside a function. It is not considered a good idea. So, you will most likely want to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                          

union test1 {
        int a;
};

int main(void)
{
        return 0;
}
```

...or this:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                          

int main(void)
{
        union {
            int a;
        } test1;

        union {
            int a;
        } test2;

        return 0;
}
```

If you really want two declarations (and one definition), you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                          

union test1;

union test1;

union test1 {
        int a;
};

int main(void)
{
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I know error, compiler say   error: redefinition of ‘union test1’, it mean redefine union test1. not variable, I confused definition of union and variable.